Is an Ultegra Shimano left side FC-R8000 crank arm compatible with newer Shimano Ultegra R8100?
I’m buying a new bike with Utegra Di2 R8100 group set. It doesn’t have a power meter. I have a power meter on my older bike with Ultegra R8000 group set. Is an Ultegra Shimano left side FC-R8000 crank arm compatible with newer Shimano Ultegra Di2 R8100?

The left cranks of Hollowtech II cranksets are independent from the rest. You can even combine different levels like 105 and Ultegra or even cheap Sora. Be sure to get the right length.
However, as MaplePanda pointed out, a difference in the Q-factor, that is in the width of the crank arms, can exist. That would make one pedal farther from the bike axis than the other. It is better to avoid this. Ultegra FC-8000 has 146 mm and Ultegra FC-8100 has 148 mm.That makes a 1 mm difference on each side. The left crankarm would place the pedal 1 mm closer to the bike.
It is possible to correct the width difference with a 1 mm shim between the pedal and the crankarm. Given that the power meter is in the crank arm and not in the pedal, it should not affect its reading, because AFAIK it was not calibrated for particular pedals. The shim may not be necessary for such a small difference, but it is available.

I don't think the situation is quite as clear cut as "all left HT2 crankarms are interchangeable". For example, Sora FC-R3000 has 150mm Q factor, whereas FC-R9100 has 146mm. I doubt that 2mm asymmetry (per side) matters much, but it would be there. Also, most MTB left crank arms cannot be replaced with road ones and vice versa (they are thicker).

@MaplePanda It did not even occur to me someone would think about MTB cranksets here. This is all about road, the question and the answer. Q-factor.. yes, might be there. I personally use a longer spindle on one side so everyone has to know how wide they need their pedals and their cranks.

Perhaps I just have poor reading comprehension, but your first paragraph did not strongly imply (to me) that the road and MTB lineups need to be considered independently.

@MaplePanda It simply did not occur to me that such implying is necessary. This is simply about road. The first sentence says that the left is independent of the right. That is universal.
